# CVS update -C - doesn't clear local changes / File status

Tags: cvs

I believe the following command:

```
CVS update -C fname
```

should clear local modifications in the file and fetch the fresh file from CVS repository.
I tried this over a locally modified file. Then gave the following command.

```
CVS st fname
```

It still shows file status as "Locally modified". Any suggestions - why first command doesn't updates the status as "Up-to-date".

Comment: The man page says "the modified file is saved in .#file.revision, however". Can you see such a file?